# why non root user cannot unshare pid namespace?

Tags: linux, namespace

`unshare -pf bash` fails with operation not permitted without *effective* root. If I don't mount proc, mount ns is not needed. Is there any particular reason creating pid ns is not allowed?

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed not allowed because it's a privileged operation: [`unshare(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/unshare.2#CLONE_NEWPID) tells:

> `CLONE_NEWPID` (since Linux 3.8)
>
> [...]
>
> **Use of `CLONE_NEWPID` requires the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability**. For further
> information, see [pid_namespaces(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/pid_namespaces.7).

What can be done instead is first to unshare a *user namespace* (which is not a privileged operation). Then as [mentioned in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669523/why-non-root-user-cannot-unshare-pid-namespace/672462#comment1268823_669523), and documented in [user_namespaces(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/user_namespaces.7#Capabilities),  unshare-ing an user namespace is enough to gain the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` within it at least until for example the next execve(), so it's not even needed to map to the root user here. Now from this new user namespace, the process can unshare a new pid namespace.

As described in pid_namespaces(7) only "the first child created by a process after a call to unshare(2) using the `CLONE_NEWPID` flag" will actually be in the new pid namespace and "has pid 1". So the fork option isn't technically needed, but it's not very useful to not have it, because only the first child process will actually be in/start the new pid namespace (and a process like `bash` not used as `bash --norc` would fork processes and lose the one chance to run one of one's choice later)

```
$ unshare -U --map-user=$(id -u) --map-group=$(id -g) -f -p
$ echo $$
1
```

This requires a recent enough version of `unshare` that has the relevant options. See note at the end when using an older version of `unshare` lacking these options.

Mounting a new instance of `/proc` reflecting the new pid namespace to actually see new pids instead of pids from parent namespace is also something that should be done:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/exe
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/proc/1/exe': Permission denied
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup 0 Sep 16 16:13 /proc/1/exe
```

As this requires mount privileges in the new namespace, this also requires to unshare a mount namespace first so the user namespace also gets privileges to perform new mounts in this new mount namespace. This still doesn't require to be root because (before the final fork and exec), the unshare process still got `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` So in the end, this could be done for some usefulness:

```
$ unshare -U --map-user=$(id -u) --map-group=$(id -g) -m --mount-proc -f -p 
$ echo $$
1
$ ls -l /proc/$$/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 0 Oct  8 21:49 /proc/1/exe -> /usr/bin/bash
```

---

Additional note: unsharing without mapping to root but mapping to the same user, when using an older version of the `unshare` command lacking `--map-user` can be done like this:

```
user@host$ echo $$; id -u; id -g; exec unshare -U -f -p
670034
1000
1000
nobody@host$ echo $$; id -u; id -g
1
65534
65534
```

then, this requires the usual help from an other process to write in the user mappings for the new user namespace (or possibly a recent version of the `unshare` command to have done this in the first place). If this process isn't privileged (commands `newuidmap` and `newgidmap` are setuid root so could set any mapping reserved for this user if needed) in the parent namespace, few choices are possible for *useful* mappings (usually root or the user itself).

other shell (still in parent namespaces):

```
user@host$ pstree -p 670034
unshare(670034)───bash(670638)
user@host$ echo '1000 1000 1' > /proc/670034/uid_map
user@host$ echo deny > /proc/670034/setgroups
user@host$ echo '1000 1000 1' > /proc/670034/gid_map
```

first shell again:

```
nobody@host$ exec bash #for cosmetic effect
user@host$ echo $$; id -u; id -g
1
1000
1000
```

Comment: Yes, I understand how and why to unshare user namesoace first. My original question was what is the potential security risk if a process without CAP_SYS_ADMIN unshares pid namespace only. Without mount namespace it'll be limited but I'm nit asking about functionality but the reason behind the decision.